# Uploading large files with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, paperclip

I want to be able to routinely upload about 3x 20mb files to a specific type of record in a Rails app. So far I'm using Paperclip and I get a pretty average success rate and a *lot* of `EOF (bad content body)` errors.

What can I do to improve the situation? Googling *rails large upload* doesn't turn much up.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading large files, while slow, should succeed.  The `EOF (bad content body)` error seems unrelated.

What are you using to upload the files?  A standard multipart web form? And is anything unusual happening with the server configuration?  Or are you using POW? Apparently POW users have reported similar [issues](https://github.com/basecamp/pow/issues/125).

For large files, I typically use S3 for storage and would recommend uploading [directly to S3](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've already poured over that POW thread even though I'm not using it. I'm using a standard web form, yeah. There's some processing after the file has been uploaded, but that obviously comes after the file is there. I can't move to S3 because of the nature of the processing.

Comment: You can but not in the way you think, you'd have to processes the file after the upload, usually in a worker queue. For very large files this has been the best way I've found to do it